# Get total occurrences of each instance in many to many pivot table

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-4

Lets say we have a many to many relation of two models, coupons and products

```
class Coupon extends \Eloquent {

  protected $table = 'coupons';

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Product extends \Eloquent {

  protected $table = 'products';

    public function coupons()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Coupon');
    }
}
```

with the pivot table just pairing the two models:

```
table: coupon_product
coupon_id, product_id
```

In the pivot table, it is possible (and valid in my case) to have multiple identical pairs, i.e.

```
coupon_id | product_id
    1            1
    1            1
    1            2
    2            1
    3            3
    3            3
```

etc.

What is the best way to get total coupons with (as an example) product id = 1, counting all occurrences of a coupon in the pivot table? The goal is to have a $coupons array passed in the view, in order to display a list of all coupons registered with product id = 1.

In the above example of the pivot table, it would be:

1. coupon 1
2. coupon 1
3. coupon 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the DB query builder:

```
DB::table('coupons')->where('product_id', 1)->get();
```

If using Eloquent ORM:

```
Product::find(1)->coupons;
```

While using the Eloquent ORM, if you wish to add some constraints on which coupons to load, you can use the following:

```
Product::find(1)->coupons()->where(some_condition)->get();
```

Comment: Thans Shishir, I was doing what you suggest for the Eloquent, without ->get() in the end and was frustrated on what was wrong... maybe you should add it to your answer as well just in case :)